# ¿Cómo seleccionar únicamente a las etiquetas que contiene texto?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero seleccionar a todas las etiquetas del DOM que contengan texto, por ejemplo:

```
$("p").not('p[innerText= ""]')
```

Cuando selecciono de esa manera, igual me trae etiquetas sin texto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta siempre usar vanilla JavaScript para optimizar el rendimiento de tu código, en este caso el objetivo es buscar todos los elementos que compartan el mismo tag y excluir aquellos que no tengan contenido, en este caso es **P** así  quévamos a crear un array para guardar los resultados de los tags que se encuentren con contenido.

```js
var result = [];
var elementos = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

function myFunction() {
 
  for (i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    if (elementos[i].innerHTML != "") {
      result.push(elementos[i].innerHTML);
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p></p>
<p>2</p>
<p></p>
<p>3</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Obten solamente los P tags con contenido</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo a través e la pseudo-clase `:empty` y a través de la función `not()` como bien has determinado.

```js
$(function () {
  let parrafos = $('p').not($('p:empty'));
  console.log(parrafos);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Uno</p>
<p>Dos</p>
<p></p>
<p>Cuatro</p>
<p></p>
<p>Seis</p>
```

**Referencia:** [:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la combinación de los selectores `:not` y `:empty`:

```
$('p:not(:empty)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con JS puro de esta forma:

Tienes un grupo de etiquetas con una clase en común:

```
<p class="elemento">Uno</p>
<p class="elemento">Dos</p>
<p class="elemento">Tres</p>
<p class="elemento">Cuatro</p>
```

- Posterior las obtienes todas en una variable por medio de `querySelectorAll()` esto devolverá un node list
- Recorres dicha variable por medio del ciclo `forEach`
- Declaras un vector vacío que almacene por ejemplo los textos de cada una, solamente donde la propiedad `innerText` sea distinto de vacía
- Imprimes el vector por fuera y así obtienes cuales si tienen texto de las que no

Código

```
let elemento = document.querySelectorAll(".elemento")
let conValor = []
elemento.forEach((etiqueta) => {
  if (etiqueta.innerText != "") {
    conValor.push(etiqueta.innerText)
  }
})
console.log(conValor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque expresamente indicas que la solución la quieres con jquery o js, lo puedes hacer fácilmente con css usando las pseudo clases :not y :empty

```
   <p>Estos</p>
  <p>párrafos</p>
   <p></p>
   <p>se</p>
   <p></p>
  <p>marcarán</p>

   p {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  }

 p:not(:empty) {
 background-color: red;
  }
```